# Get random name of json, but it is not random

Tags: json, reactjs

As soon as the user loads or reloads the page, a method should be triggered which searches out a random number and with this random number the JSON with the same ID should be selected. Afterwards the name should be displayed.

How do I do this?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import JSONFile from "./data.json";


const Input = () => {
    const showQuote = () => {
        const randomInt = getRandomInt(3) + 1;
        const data = InspirationalQuote.find((randomInt) => randomInt.id);
        setRandomText(data.text);
  };

  const [randomText, setRandomText] = useState("");
  window.addEventListener("load", showQuote);
        
    
    
      function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      }
    
    return (
        <div> {randomText} </div>
 );
};

export default Input;
import Input from "./Input.js"
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Input></Input>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "abc"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "def"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "ghi"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you know what your own code does?

Comment: Please add a codesandbox or more code to help you.

Comment: @Melvynx I have tried to improve it, is that enough so far?

Comment: @ChloeAnderson sure, unfortunately I had a copy & paste error, so please have a look at my edit

Comment: Okay, this is how I understand it; 
You want to generate a random number and match it with the JSON data and display that exact JSON data that has the id same as the random number generated,

example: random number results to "2" then name "def" should be displayed 

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @RobertAzarSammie correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is how I understand it; You want to generate a random number and match it with the JSON data and display that exact JSON data that has the id same as the random number generated, example: random number results to "2" then name "def" should be displayed Is this assumption correct?

Firstly: if the JSON data is stored in JSONFile then you have to do something like;

```
var jd = JSON.parse(JSONFile);
```

If your getRandomInt function is working correctly then store the generated number in a variable

Maybe something like this

```
const randNum = getRandomInt(3)
```

then finally check to see if the randomly generated number matches the json data.

```
    if(jd.id == randNum){
//display the json data
 //jd.name
}
```

Am just trying to make you understand the logic to build upon. THanks